# subseting columns by the name of rows of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I need to subset the columns of a dataframe taking into account the rownames of another dataframe.(in R)

Im trying to select the representative species of Brazilian Amazon subseting a great Brazilian database taking into account the percentage of representative location, information which is in another dataframe

```
> a <- data.frame("John" = c(2,1,1,2), "Dora" = c(1,1,3,2), "camilo" = c(1:4),"alex"=c(1,2,1,2))
> a
  John Dora camilo alex
1    2    1      1    1
2    1    1      2    2
3    1    3      3    1
4    2    2      4    2
> b <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Age" = c(15,31,2), "Name" = c("John","Dora","alex"))
> b
  SN Age Name
1  1  15 John
2  2  31 Dora
3  3   2 alex
> result <- a[,rownames(b)[1:3]]
Error in `[.data.frame`(a, , rownames(b)[1:3]) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I want to get this dataframe

```
  John Dora   alex
1    2    1      1    
2    1    1      2
3    1    3      1
4    2    2      2
```

Comment: You can do `a[as.character(b$Name)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple `a[,b$Name]` does not work because `b$Name` is considered a factor. Be careful because it won't throw an error but you will get the wrong answer!

But this is easy to fit by using `a[,as.character(b$Name)]`instead!